# Label consecutive runs of a sequence in a column with consecutive letters

Tags: r, sequence

I have the following data:

```
df <- data.frame(week = rep(seq(1, 4, by=1), times = 3) )

   week
1     1
2     2
3     3
4     4
5     1
6     2
7     3
8     4
9     1
10    2
11    3
12    4
```

I want to label each consecutive runs of 1:4 with a letter so that the result is this:

```
   week episode
1     1       a
2     2       a
3     3       a
4     4       a
5     1       b
6     2       b
7     3       b
8     4       b
9     1       c
10    2       c
11    3       c
12    4       c
```

I have tried the following but this does not distinguish the separate consecutive runs of the sequence 1:4

```
data.frame(df, episode = letters[cumsum(c(1L, diff(df$week) > 1L))]) 
   week episode
1     1       a
2     2       a
3     3       a
4     4       a
5     1       a
6     2       a
7     3       a
8     4       a
9     1       a
10    2       a
11    3       a
12    4       a
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is already in a sequence, then just do the cumulative of logical vector (`week == 1`)

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    mutate(episode =  letters[cumsum(week == 1)])
#   week episode
#1     1       a
#2     2       a
#3     3       a
#4     4       a
#5     1       b
#6     2       b
#7     3       b
#8     4       b
#9     1       c
#10    2       c
#11    3       c
#12    4       c
```

---

Or using `base R` (without any additional packages)

```
df$episode <- letters[cumsum(df$week == 1)]
```

Comment: Thank you that works! For my understanding, how does taking the cumulative of logical vector week==1 give this result?

Comment: @fega  `df$week == 1` returns a logical vector of TRUE/FALSE. an TRUE/FALSE are stored as 1/0.  When we do `cumsum`, it adds 1 were there is 1

Answer (score 1):

A different `dplyr` possibility could be:

```
df %>%
 mutate(episode = letters[gl(n()/4, 4)])

   week episode
1     1       a
2     2       a
3     3       a
4     4       a
5     1       b
6     2       b
7     3       b
8     4       b
9     1       c
10    2       c
11    3       c
12    4       c
```

Or the same with `base R`:

```
df$episode = letters[gl(length(df$week)/4, 4)]
```

Or:

```
df %>%
 mutate(episode = letters[ceiling(seq_along(week)/4)])
```

Or the same with `base R`:

```
df$episode = letters[ceiling(seq_along(df$week)/4)]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `rowid` from the `data.table` package

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)

df[, episode := letters[rowid(week)]]

#     week episode
#  1:    1       a
#  2:    2       a
#  3:    3       a
#  4:    4       a
#  5:    1       b
#  6:    2       b
#  7:    3       b
#  8:    4       b
#  9:    1       c
# 10:    2       c
# 11:    3       c
# 12:    4       c
```

Comment: This is nifty way